# Why does part of a script executed by cron fail unless stderr is directed to /dev/null?

Tags: linux, bash, scripting, cron

Here is a snippet from a script which I generally execute from cron:

```
if [ "$RESCAN_COMMAND" = "wipecache" ]; then
    log "Linking cover art."
    find $FLAC_DIR -name "*.jpg" | while read f; do c=`echo $f | sed -e 's/flac/mp3/g'`; ln -s "$f" "$c"; done
    log "Done linking cover art"
fi
```

The script works perfectly when run from the command line. But when run by cron (as the same user) it fails somewhere in the `find` line. The "Done" message is not logged and the script does not continue beyond the `if` block.

The `find` line creates links from files like `flac/Artist/Album/cover.jpg` to `mp3/Artist/Album/cover.jpg`. There are a few hundred files to link. The command generates a lot of output to `stderr`, because most, if not all, of the links already exist.

On a hunch, I tried redirecting the `stderr` of the `ln` command to `/dev/null`:

```
    find $FLAC_DIR -name "*.jpg" | while read f; do c=`echo $f | sed -e 's/flac/mp3/g'`; ln -s "$f" "$c" 2>/dev/null; done
```

With that change, the script executes successfully from cron (as well as from the command line).

I would be interested to understand why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's probably producing too much output. This really isn't a bug, but a feature as cron typically send emails with it's output. MTA's don't like text messages with many many lines, so cron just quits. Maybe the silent quit is a bug though.

You could also use ln -f to suppress the ln errors in only the case of pre-existing files.

Comment: I'm accepting this answer because you actually explained the reason why the cron failed, which is what I asked for. (Also, ln -f is neater than redirecting to /dev/null. I've amended my script to do that.)

Answer (score 3):

Could it be this bug report: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/cron/+bug/151231

Comment: Thanks. It looks like the fix would be to specify an (empty) MTA. I will try that.